# How to create a variable number of dimensions for mgrid

Tags: python-3.x, numpy

I would like to create a meshgrid of variable dimensions by specifying the dimensions with a variable i.e. specifying dim=2, rather than manually changing the expression as in the example below to set a 2D mesh grid.

How would I implement a wrapper function for this?

The problem stems from not being familiar with the syntax that mgrid uses ([index_tricks](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/main/numpy/lib/index_tricks.py)).

```
import numpy as np

mgrid = np.mgrid[
                  -5:5:5j,
                  -5:5:5j,
                ]
```

Observed [documentation](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.mgrid.html) for mgrid, but there seems to be no info on setting the number of dimensions with a variable.

Comment: you could use `np.meshgrid` with your own arrays created with `np.linspace` (or `arange`).  `mgrid` is an index trick, not a fundamental function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a tuple containing the slice manually, and repeat it some number of times:

```
import numpy as np

num_dims = 2

mgrid = np.mgrid[(slice(-5, 5, 5j),) * num_dims]
```